# Como adicionar dias em uma data com o formato dd/mm/yyyy em powerapps?

Tags: data, powerbi, fórmula

Estou pegando uma data de uma tabela e adicionando dias na contagem no powerapps. Aparentemente no computador funciona, mas quando uso o aplicativo do powerapps no celular nao funciona, a data vem trocada, ao invés de vir dd/mm/yyyy vem mm/dd/yyyy.
O código abaixo cria o valor para a label 18:

```
Text(DateValue(Label17.Text);"[$-pt-BR]dd/mm/yyyy";"pt-BR")
```

E o código abaixo adiciona a quantidade de dias na data:

```
DateAdd(DateValue(Label18.Text);Value(ThisItem.Qtde_dias_para_contato);Days)
```

Não entendo o porquê de funcionar no computador e no celular não. É alguma configuração do celular?

Answer (score -1):

é porque no texto você definiu o Padrão pt-BR, e no DateAdd vc precisa passar a formatação pois o padrão é US